# Application of Ito's formula to Liouville's theorem

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Liouville's theorem for bounded harmonic functions could be proved using Ito's formula, martingale convergence and Blumenthal's 0-1 law.

I tried checking the classical books on Brownian motion and stochastic calculus, it's either available as an exercise (with no reference) or not mentioned at all.

Do you know where to find the original work proving Liouville's theorem applying Ito's formula?